# check method type if it is public, private or protected

Tags: php, oop

Is any way to check method type in php if it is public, private or protected?

what I tried:
I have class and it have methods I can put this methods in url and grt pages so I need a way if the users put the private methods in url then the user get an error page such as "Access denied"

Ex:

```
if (method_type ('Get_user') == 'private'){
    header ("location: ./")
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking method visibility in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981622/checking-method-visibility-in-php)

Comment: You should not confuse (or mix) access rights with the visibility of methods. Your program design should not be dependent on what users can access. ----------
For the record: it [How to check if a function is public or protected in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160901/how-to-check-if-a-function-is-public-or-protected-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use ReflectionMethods
Check Link http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php

```
    $reflection = new ReflectionMethod('className', $functionName);
        if ($reflection->isPublic()) {
            echo "Public method";
        }
       if ($reflection->isPrivate()) {
            echo "Private method";
        }
       if ($reflection->isProtected()) {
            echo "Protected method";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$check = new ReflectionMethod('class', 'method');
if($check->isPublic()){
    echo "public";
} elseif($check->isPrivate()){
    echo "private";
} else{
    echo "protected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Reflection](http://php.net/reflection) class, such as
[ReflectionMethod::isPrivate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isprivate.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ReflectionMethod, check the following link for more info on it:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php

Also you might try to use is_callable but that relates to scope so it will yield a different result depending on the class you're in. You can check it out here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php